# How to find Mysql thread

Tags: mysql, linux, multithreading

I am using mytop, to search for slow queries. And for example I found that Thread with ID 110 is slow
[image]

But there is now such thread in my system. 
ps -AL

[image]
[image]

What could be wrong? Why I doesn't see Thread with ID 110? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the ID you see in mytop is the mysql connection id, and it is local to mysql. mytop doesn't show you any process ids (the process could even be running on a remote machine).

If you want to find the process, you'll need to use mysqladmin and netstat:

```
$ mysqladmin -v pr
+-----+------+----------------------+-------+---------+------+------------+-----------------------+
| Id  | User | Host                 | db    | Command | Time | State      | Info                  |
+-----+------+----------------------+-------+---------+------+------------+-----------------------+
| 4   | uqos | 192.168.170.66:33912 | us200 | Sleep   | 8    |            |                       |
| 5   | uqos | 192.168.170.66:33913 | us200 | Sleep   | 8    |            |                       |
| 6   | uqos | 192.168.170.66:33914 | us200 | Sleep   | 8    |            |                       |
| 251 | uqos | 192.168.170.66:59161 | us200 | Query   | 2    | User sleep | select sleep(200)     
| 254 | uqos | localhost            |       | Query   | 0    |            | show full processlist |
+-----+------+----------------------+-------+---------+------+------------+-----------------------
```

So, someone from host 192.168.170.66 is connecting to the mysql db from port 59161. Lets move over to that machine and find that process:

```
$ netstat -apn |grep 59161
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 192.168.170.66:59161        192.168.170.60:3306         ESTABLISHED 13166/mysql
$ ps -ef |grep 13166
uqos     13166  6635  0 14:31 pts/0    00:00:00 mysql -h 192.168.170.60 us200 -p
```

There we go, it's the process with pid 13166

This is not possible atm. if the client connects with unix sockets though, only if they connect with TCP.

Comment: Oh, so connection Id, even better than POSIX thread ID that was my initial guess. +1